# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/GenericFilter

Tags: spring-boot

I am using jsp as front end in spring boot app. I deployed application on localhost through tomcat8 manager and application runs perfectly. But when I follow same steps of deployment on hosting server I am getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/GenericFilter
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at
```

Hence I included dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and after updating project I have javax.servlet in my classpath and in war file also. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: With spring boot you really don’t need to be adding anything like that to your Pom. Post your pom.xml